# padding or space from text to underline

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a website: [Website](https://mimsi.dk/). In the menubar I have an underline when a specifi menu is active, or you hover over the menu options.

I would like that there is some px space from the menu text to the underline. How is that possible?

I tried to set a `border-bottom:1px solid white`, but that does not do the trick for me.

It is the following CSS the underline is on:

```
.wpmega-black-white .wpmm-mega-wrapper > li:hover,
.wpmega-black-white .wpmm-mega-wrapper > li.current-menu-item {
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-top: 0.8em;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Yeah okay that make sence what you are writing :-) Text-decoration makes an underline on the text, nothing else. 

How can I make a positioned pseudo-element on the inner span? unfortunately I am lost on that one :-/

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**
delete previous codes and modify your CSS as I wrote:
in your CSS files `/css/style.css?ver=4.9.4` find and change these block of codes. please have a backup before modifinig
please note that you should not delete other parameters of elements, only change what I wrote.

```
   .wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmm-orientation-horizontal ul.wpmm-mega-wrapper > li > a {
        padding: 20px 15px 10px 20px;
    }
    .wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmm-orientation-horizontal ul.wpmm-mega-wrapper > li.current-menu-item a, .wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmm-orientation-vertical ul.wpmm-mega-wrapper > li.current-menu-item a{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    }
    .wp-megamenu-main-wrapper.wpmm-orientation-horizontal.wpmm-askins-wrapper ul.wpmm-mega-wrapper > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
        top: 60%;
    }
```

add this to your own css file

```
.wp-mega-menu-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I can see your code is almost working how I want. So when the menu is active the line should also be under. How can I do that? I tried to set `span.wpmm-mega-menu-href-title:active`, but that is not working? The code on my webpage is your now.

Comment: I have updated the code, simply add `class='active'` to your active span.

Comment: Thanks. I just added your new code, but it still do not do the job with underlining when active.

Comment: your code should be like this `<span class="wpmm-mega-menu-href-title active">HJEM</span>`

Comment: Ah okay. It is a Wordpress site, so pretty annoying :-( I thought I could do it in the css, without touching the html code. I hate messing around in the html code for a WP site.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. It sets the underline on all the menu at the same time.

Comment: we need to change few codes, as wordpress has classes for current page class. I will write you shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165091/discussion-between-abbas-nabilou-and-mcduck4).

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration` does exactly what is says it does, underline the text...you can't move the location of that underline (yet). You would have to use a positioned pseudo-element on the inner span.

For example:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #000;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li>a {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: "Work Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li>a span {
  position: relative;
}

li>a span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  /* adjust spacing here */
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width .3s ease;
  background: transparent;
}

li>a.current-item span::after {
  background: currentcolor;
  width: 100%;
}

li>a:hover span::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="'" class="current-item"><span>MY TEXT HERE</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="'" class=""><span>MY NEW ITEM</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This also means they can be animated.

Comment: pseudo elements are not supported by all browsers!! when it can be done by border-bottom it is not necessary to use pseudo elements!

Comment: Pseudo-element **are** supported by all browsers at least modern ones above IE8+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: it is not all of them!! don't try to impose your idea!! accept that my answer is right!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just updated my page with the code. So I get the line where I want now, but why are the lines there all the time, and not only when the menu is active or hover?

Comment: The code is *just an example*...you will have to adapt it for active & hover in *your code*.